# Array mapping with multiple properties

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to map multiple nested arrays to one.

For instance:

```
public class HomeDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TranslatedHome
{
    public string NameEn { get; set; }
    public string NameZh { get; set; }
}
```

I want to merge HomeDto[] to TranslatedHome[] wherein TranslatedHome[] I have fulfilled NameEn.
I know how to distinguish language but, but it's not relevant for the question.

How can I map   HomeDto[] which contains data for ZH language into TranslatedHome ?

Comment: _"I know how to distinguish language but, but it's not relevant for the question."_ - And what is the question?

Comment: @John I have updated post.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're asking for. Are you asking how to instantiate a new array, loop through the source array, and populate the new array with new objects? Are you asking how to translate Chinese names to English? What?

Comment: I have array TranslatedHome with English and I would like to add Chinese to this array based  on HomeDto[]

Comment: Wait, are you saying that you have two pre-existing arrays and you want to copy data from one to the other?

Comment: That's right, but with not union

Comment: Do both arrays have the same number of elements in the same order?

Comment: for the clarification, you have multilingual names in HomeDto[] and you want to separate them by their language in another collection, is it?

Comment: @John yes, they have the same number in the same order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to apply a property from each item of one array to a corresponding property in each item a of second array.

You should use a `for` loop for this:

```
// I assume you have these somewhere.
// obviously they should both be initialized, be the same length, and the items
// should be in the same order for the code below to work.
HomeDto[] src;
TranslatedHome[] dest;

for (int i = 0; i < src.Length; ++i)
{
    dest[i].NameZh = src[i].Name;
}
```

Comment: How about the situation the data is not in the same order?

Comment: @mskuratowski I couldn't possibly comment. After all, I'm a programmer, not a magician. :)

Comment: In short: through your comments and code above you have indicated that the only common thing between the two arrays is the order of the elements and the size of the arrays. With the information provided, combining the data in any other way would be nothing more than complete guesswork.

Comment: In the case they are not in the same order I will advice that you learn Zh language, and match them by hand into a better object where the order cannot be lost. Either with ID or with ID and untranslated source.